# Javaプログラムを実行すると「int型をint[]に変換できません」のエラーが出てしまう

Tags: java

下記のプログラムを記載すると、int型をint[]に変換できませんというエラーが出ました。
行いたい処理としては、二次元配列に[0][0]から[9][9]まで設定し、1から100まで要素を代入したいのですが、エラーのため実行できません。様々な場所を探しましたがわからなかったので投稿致しました。何かアドバイスを頂けないでしょうか？
宜しくお願い申し上げます。

```
package kadai;

public class Kadai1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int [][] Array= new int[10][10];

        for(int Count=0;Count<10;Count++) {
            Array[Count] =Count+1;
            for(int Count2=0;Count<10;Count2++)
            {
                Array[Count2] = Count2+1;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: 参考:[10x10 2D Array With Output 1-100](https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/214494-10x10-2d-array-with-output-1-100/) (解答には書き間違いがありますけれども)

Comment: 本題とは関係ありませんが、2つ目のforループで打ち間違いをしているので注意してください :)　`for(int Count2=0;Count<10;Count2++)` の真ん中の終了条件が間違っています。

Answer (score 1):

下のように宣言・代入しているため、変数 `Array` は int の二次元配列になっています。つまり `Array` は int の配列の配列です。

```java
int[][] Array = new int[10][10];
```

しかしいくつかの行では、以下のように代入を行っています。これがエラーの原因です。

```java
Array[Count] = Count + 1;
```

左辺は「int の配列」ですが、右辺は「int」です。

int の値を代入するのであれば、`Array[なんとか][かんとか]` のように 2 つの添え字を指定する必要があります。

今回の課題の範囲であれば、二次元配列 `Array` は Excel のような表であるというイメージがぴったりです。表の各セルに int の値が入っていますが、どのセルに代入するか決めるためには「列」と「行」の 2 つを指定しないといけません。今回のエラーは「列」しか指定してないのに int を代入しようとしているのでエラーが出ています。

```
    0   1   2   ..
  -------------
0 |   |   |   |
  -------------
1 |   |   |   |
  -------------
2 |   |   |   |
  -------------
:
```